# How to simplify ifelse argument Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I have this code and im getting the error "expected command" I know it most certainly its a brackets problem but I ve looked and cant figure out where is it even when netlogo is showing it.

the second If else is the one highlighted by the error, the one with distancia agua. I think a fresher and more keen set of eyes can spot it in no time. Thanks in advance.

```
ifelse ambiente_natural[move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius 6 and pcolor = 55 and pycor < 80]ask patches in-radius (1 + random 2) [if pcolor != blue [set pcolor 35]]ask patches with [pycor > 80] [set pcolor 68]]
    [
      move-to one-of patches with 
      [not any? other turtles in-radius 6 and pcolor = 55]
      [ifelse distancia_agua <= 15 
        [ask patches in-radius (2 + random 2) 
          [if pcolor != blue 
            [set pcolor 35]
        ]
        ]
      
        [ifelse distancia_agua > 15 and distancia_agua <= 35 
          [ask patches in-radius (1 + random 2) [if pcolor != blue 
            [set pcolor 35]
          ]
          ]
        
          [if distancia_agua > 35 and <= 60 
            [ask patches in-radius 1 [if pcolor != blue 
              [set pcolor 35]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of debugging, you may find it helpful to have a very consistent structure- then you can [highlight all your code and hit "Tab"](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/codetab.html#automatic-indentation) to auto-format and hopefully identify the problem area. Here is one version of that- I commented the two places that *seem* to be the problems:

```
globals [ ambiente_natural distancia_agua ]

to test
  ifelse ambiente_natural 
  ; Ifelse 1-1
  [
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius 6 and pcolor = 55 and pycor < 80] 
    ask patches in-radius (1 + random 2) [ 
      if pcolor != blue [set pcolor 35] 
    ]
    ask patches with [pycor > 80] [
      set pcolor 68
    ]
  ]
  ; Ifelse 1-2
  [
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius 6 and pcolor = 55]
    ; There was an extra brace here
    ifelse distancia_agua <= 15 
    ; Ifelse 2-1
    [ 
      ask patches in-radius (2 + random 2) [ 
        if pcolor != blue [
          set pcolor 35
        ]
      ]
    ]
    ; Ifelse 2-2
    [ 
      ifelse distancia_agua > 15 and distancia_agua <= 35 
      ; Ifelse 3-1
      [
        ask patches in-radius (1 + random 2) [
          if pcolor != blue [
            set pcolor 35
          ]
        ]
      ]
      ; Ifelse 3-2
      [   
        if distancia_agua > 35 and distancia_agua <= 60 [ ; This wasmissing the second "distancia_agua"
          ask patches in-radius 1 [
            if pcolor != blue [
              set pcolor 35
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks! that auto formating is a total win! That one Brace that i didnt see. Thanks again! its working like a charm now. Have a good day

Comment: @bksnlow - you bet, auto formatting is a lifesaver! Happy to help